# Does Uber driver trips API's start city latitude longitude change for each trip within same city?

Tags: uber-api

Does the

`trips[].start_city.latitude` and `trips[].start_city.longitude`

in the Uber Driver's API change based on the street where you pick up?

e.g 
Assume the driver is doing multiple pickups within San Francisco.

Would the `lat` and `long` in the json point to exact location on map where the trip began?

OR

Will it always show the same `lat` and `long` for every trip.

PS: I do not have access to real data for a Uber Driver.The sandbox response for multiple trips https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/guides/sandbox#trips

have the same latitude and longitude.

```
"start_city": {
            "latitude": 37.7749,
            "display_name": "San Francisco",
            "longitude": -122.4194
        },
```

It is safe to assume that all the pick ups were not happening at the same location every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. It just shows the lat/long for the start city of the trip. This does not change for multiple trips within that city that started in different locations within that city.

https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-trips-get